# Save Node Title By database query

Tags: nodes

I am trying to update a node title by database query as

```
 $num_updated = db_update('node') // Table name no longer needs {}
  ->fields(array(
    'title' => "custom_title",
    'status' => 1,
  ))
  ->condition('nid', $nid, '=')
  ->execute();
```

The above code is updating the node title in node table, but on node display I am not seeing the updated title.

The reason I am not using node_save() to update node title is to by pass auto entity label functionality for updating node title.

Comment: may be flushing the cache after the query can help?

Comment: @xurshid29 I tried clearing the caches.

Comment: I think you need to save title field also with `field_attach_update` and reset cache. You can also take a look at `node_save` function.

Comment: I tried with field_attach_update also

Comment: @xurshid29 the reason field_attach_update is not working is the same, it does not update node_revision table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bypass just one functionality, you need to go thorough all your modules, see what they are doing on `node_save()` and emulate it with your queries. Most common thing people forget is to update revisions, menus and clear cache. But your way is discouraged.

Instead, you should be able to configure [Automatic Entity Label](https://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) not to override title, if the title is set manually, like on the screenshot below:

[image: config screenshot]

If you need to deny users title generation, you can change this setting in code with `variable_set()` just before call to `node_save()`, and revert it just after.

Comment: thanks @Molot I was trying to fix this for last 3 hours :)

Comment: @arpitr happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 3):

You also need to update the node_revision table. You either need to create a new revision for that node or update the latest one.

Comment: @m1no you are right if the title needs to be updated with database query than we need to update the revision table title as well and this is the answer for the title of question I have, but with Molot answer I am able to fix with cleaner way, thanks :)